# Insert imagem.jpg no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, query

Bom dia! 
Eu pretendo inserir uma imagem no banco de dados no formato .jpg, porém quando é inserido ele aparece assim na base de dados: ????JFIF 
Aqui está o meu código referente à imagem:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="imagem" placeholder="Insira a imagem do produto" required/>
</form>
<?php
    $imagem_produto=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']));
    $inserir_produto=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO produtos (imagem) VALUES('{$imagem_produto}')");
?>
```

O que queria era que na base de dados aparecesse o nome e a extensão da imagem, por exemplo "imagem.jpg" sómente isso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer apenas o nome, porque não usa assim?

```
$nome_img = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/".$nome_img)){
   $inserir=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO coluna(nome) VALUES ('$nome_img')");
}else{
   echo "Erro!";
}
```

Com isto você irá inserir a imagem na base de dados.

Eu suponho que você tem um código para o upload mas deixo aqui na mesma.

Saliento ainda que eu costumo usar `varchar(255)` na base de dados.

Comment: O nome e a extensão! pois sem a extensão não vai valer de nada :/

Comment: Com isso ele vai buscar ambos

Comment: Sim eu também estou a usar varchar. Eu tentei implementar o seu código, porém dá erro , não diz qual... E  já agora no seu `if` "images/ seria o nome da pasta certo?

Comment: @Ana Sim mas dá erro em que linha? Você faz o `submit` do formulário?

Comment: Não diz qual a linha que dá erro, aparece o erro que vem do `echo "erro";` E sim faço submit do formulário

Comment: O caminho daquela pasta está certo?

Comment: @Ana isso quer dizer que não conseguiu mover a image que foi carregada para a pasta final, neste caso `images`. Provavelmente o caminho para a pasta `images` é diferente.

Comment: O caminho para a pasta no meu caso seria `../images/` e sim ele encontra-se correto :/ , peço desculpa o incomodo já agora...

Comment: Mas está a funcionar direito?

Comment: Bom, agradeço a ajuda a todos, já está a funcionar finalmente!!

Comment: esse código dá-me erro com o ";" na query

Comment: @JoséGomes como assim?

Comment: ao por no meu projeto esse código ele dá erro no ; da query

Comment: era por faltar um ")" aqui -- if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/".$nome_img){

Comment: @JoséGomes Obrigado! Irei corrigir imediatamente

Answer (score 1):

O campo da tabela onde vai parar a tua imagem têm de ser blob ou mediumblob consoante o tamanho que precisas! Depois é só mostrares a row no lado que precises e ela vai aparecer!

**Código para inserir imagem**

Faz um botão e faz lhe submit com o name="submit"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


 $name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
 $target_file = basename($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);

 // Select file type
 $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 // Se quiseres só jpg deixa só jpg
  $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

 // Check extension
 if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

 // Convert to base64 
 $image_base64 = 
 base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem'] 
['tmp_name']) );
 $image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;


$query="INSERT INTO produtos(imagem) VALUES ('".$image."')";
$query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: AlmostDone, obrigada pela ajuda, eu fiz igualzinho,  e sim eu já tinha criado um botão submit, o problema é que agora na base de dados aparece `data:image/jpg;base6` eu queria que aparecesse por exemplo `imagem.jpg`

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta mas porquê necessita isso assim?

Comment: Porque estou a fazer uma loja virtual, e para mosrar os produtos é por exemplo:  `<img src="images/<?php echo $row['imagem']; ?>" alt="">` por isso para funcionar na base de dados deve se encontrar somente o nome e a extensão do ficheiro, pois para mostrar já indico o nome da pasta, e assim fica `images/imagem.jpg`

Comment: Porque simplesmente não faz uma coluna imagem do tipo mediumblob e mantém só <img src ="<?php echo $row['imagem']; ?> e se fizer como disse em cima ele vai buscar diretamente a foto na database!

Comment: Agora já vou tarde, pois já tenho mais de 200 produtos inseridos, e todos eu inseri à mão, eu praticamente já acabei o projeto!

Comment: Você deveria ter feito um ciclo while para repetir os registos da base de dados! Assim não sei como ajudá-la

Comment: Sim eu fiz um ciclo while para rodar todos os registos!

Comment: Pois o único problema na alteração que propus nos comentários é que você teria que inserir os 200 produtos todos outra vez!

Comment: Prefiro não arriscar, pois nao consigo apagar agora a tabela toda, pois tenho várias chaves estrangeiras etc

Comment: Sim obviamente que não boa sorte nisso e peço desculpa por não ter conseguido ajudar.

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum, para a próxima tentarei desse jeito! Obrigada